# Batch script using dtexec does not succeed after recent windows updates

Tags: sql-server, windows, visual-studio, batch-file, ssis

My PC caught up with about 2 months worth of updates last Friday. Now I cannot launch SSIS with batch scripts. Tried adding the Microsoft.sqlserver.manageddts.dll to the C:\Windows\System32 Directory using the gacutil.exe. It is showing as the 11.0.5058.0 version.  Readout of batch below.

```
Started:  3:43:52 PM
Info: 2017-05-19 15:43:52.75
   Code: 0x40019316
   Source:  Package Format Migration Module
   Description: The provider name for the connection manager "<Instance Name>" has been changed from "SQLNCLI10.1" to "SQLNCLI11".
End Info
Info: 2017-05-19 15:43:52.76
   Code: 0x40016019
   Source:  
   Description: The package format was migrated from version 3 to version 6. It must be saved to retain migration changes.
End Info
Warning: 2017-05-19 15:43:54.95
   Code: 0x00000000
   Source: Newest File Script Newest File Script
   Description: Found SQL Server Integration Services 2008 Script Task "ST_02497875f0894cd2bcce80dd7c3dcXXXX" that requires migration!
End Warning
Error: 2017-05-19 15:43:54.97
   Code: 0x00000003
   Source: Newest File Script Newest File Script
   Description: There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5XXXX'
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.VstaHelper.<CleanUp>b__1b()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.MtaExecution.Run(Action action)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.VstaHelper.CleanUp()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.DisposeVstaHelper()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.MigrateVSTA21ScriptProject(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5XXXX
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.VSTA.VSTA11, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080XXXX.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
End Error
Info: 2017-05-19 15:43:55.03
   Code: 0x4001F300
   Source: SPDlabel 
   Description: Succeeded in upgrading the package.
End Info
Info: 2017-05-19 15:43:55.04
   Code: 0x4004300A
   Source: Export TXT file SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: Validation phase is beginning.
End Info
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have installed?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)   Jun 11 2012 16:41:53   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have some later version tools installed, which perhaps were added to your path.

It's trying to upgrade your package on the fly, and failing.

SQL 2008's dtexec.exe will be under something like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn
```

Try explicitly running that one instead.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.